# how to handle iPhone popups automatically without any user interaction?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, popup

I'm working on a tool that helps to automate Browser based products. On of the use case I encountered is to handle popups either from application or from Safari. I would like to provide an API where a user can click OK when a popup prompts. Can I do it through JS or is it possible through any Apple API? And one more thing, how do I know a popup has appeared? Any pointers will help. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by popup? Are you talking about a UIAlertView?

Answer (score 4):

Not possible at all - except in your own app that features its own browser.